# OpenSSL DTLSv1_listen: server cannot get a message from client

Tags: udp, openssl, listen

I have a huge problem! And I need your help! Please help me!

I have found an example of DTLS implementation in the Internet, it is called `dtls_udp_echo.c`.
And I have the following code in function which describes behavior of server:

> ```
>     memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
>
>
>     /* Create BIO */
>
>     bio = BIO_new_dgram(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
>
>
>     /* Set and activate timeouts */
>
>     timeout.tv_sec = 5;
>
>     timeout.tv_usec = 0;
>
>     BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);
>
>
>     ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
>
>     cout << "ssl is" << ssl ;
>
>     printf("ssl is \n");
>
>     SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
>
>     SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_COOKIE_EXCHANGE);
>
>
>     while (DTLSv1_listen(ssl, &client_addr) <= 0){
>
>         //printf("%d\n",DTLSv1_listen(ssl, &client_addr));
>
>     }
>
>     info = (struct pass_info*) malloc (sizeof(struct pass_info));
>
>     memcpy(&info->server_addr, &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
>
>     memcpy(&info->client_addr, &client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
>
>     info->ssl = ssl;
>
>     if (pthread_create( &tid, NULL, connection_handle, info) != 0) {
>
>         perror("pthread_create");
>
>         exit(-1);
>
>     }
>
> }
>
> THREAD_cleanup();
> ```

I've created client and it've sent a message to server. Using TCPDUMP I can see that packet

```
60. 250026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59389, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 104) 127.0.0.1.8001 > 127.0.0.1.8000: UDP, length 76
```

where:

```
127.0.0.1 port 8001 - client
127.0.0.1 port 8000 - server
```

But server seems to be blind and it does not sent a handshake back to client. 
I believe addresses are correct because when I during experiments changed them client didn't manage to send a handshake to server and there was an error:

```
SSL_connect: Connection refused
error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

My openSSL's version is 1.0.0d

Thank you, friend for you try to help me!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say exactly what your problem is, but a couple of ideas that might help you search.

Set message and info callbacks, info_cb and msg_cb are functions you have to provide:

```
SSL_set_info_callback(ssl, info_cb);
SSL_set_msg_callback(ssl, msg_cb);
```

Does DTLSv1_listen ever return? In that case, what does it return?

You can also call

```
SSL_state_string_long(ssl)
```

That returns a description of the current state of ssl.

If you are on Windows, the examples you refer to doesn't work since Windows does not handle multiple UDP sockets bound to the same address and port as expected by the examples. To work around that, please see http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/DTLS_Implementation_Notes.